# Can I add a subsite as a hub to a different hub?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, sub-site, hub-site

I am seeking recommendation on below :

Can I add a sub site as a hub to a different hub in SharePoint online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot add a hub site to another hub site. This not possible by design

Reference - [SharePoint hub sites new in Office 365](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint-Blog/SharePoint-hub-sites-new-in-Office-365/ba-p/109547)